# MySQL REPLACE doesn't works how expected

Tags: mysql

My table (name is primary key, id is unique key):

```
||   name   || id ||    col_1    ||
===================================
||  test1   ||1234||   test999   ||
```

Query:

```
REPLACE INTO `table` (`name`, `col_1`) VALUES ('NOTTEST1', 'test999').
```

In this case, it mustn't replace row, but it does. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19820724/replace-into-query-syntax

Comment: I know it. In my case there is no same primary key, but it replaces.

Comment: You just said yourself that name is your primary key in the question.

Comment: Yes. In query name is NOTTEST1, but in table name is test1.

Comment: Show the table definition

Answer (score 0):

It works well!

can you check if table structure is set correctly. Here's what I did:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `name` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col_1` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

insert  into `test`(`name`,`id`,`col_1`) values ('test1',1234,'test999');
```

And when I tried this:

```
REPLACE INTO test (`name`,`col_1`) VALUES('test11','admin');
```

It created a new record.