# Insert or update column from one mySQL table to another error

Tags: php, mysql

I have the table `behaviour` where I count the pages of each hash. I want to transfer the results into a new table `new_table`.
If the `hash` on `new_table` exists, then just update the number of `pages`.
Otherwhise, if it is a new `hash` found on `behaviour` that did not inserted yet to `new_table` just add it.

```
INSERT INTO new_table (hash, pages)
SELECT hash, COUNT( id ) AS pages
FROM behaviour
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE new_table.pages=behaviour.pages
GROUP BY hash
```

I get an error on the 5th line "group by hash".
What am I doing wrong?

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY hash' at line 5

Comment: what error ??
Is it syntax error ??

Comment: @Priyanshu hello, i updated my question. thank you

Comment: check below answer

Comment: Maybe you can use "Replace Into" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19820724/replace-into-query-syntax

Comment: @Phenix can you show me how?

Comment: @villoui
Have a look at my provided link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below query. This will work

```
INSERT INTO new_table (hash, pages)
SELECT hash, COUNT( id ) AS pages
FROM behaviour GROUP BY hash
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE pages=VALUES(pages)
```

You Must add the group by clause before the on duplicate key check

Comment: maybe the problem is because the COUNT( id ) AS pages from behaviour is not passed to the new_table.pages as a number

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO new_table (hash, pages)
SELECT hash, COUNT( id ) AS pages
FROM behaviour
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE new_table.pages=behaviour.pages
GROUP BY hash;
```

Try this

Comment: I added  ' ; ' (semicolon) at the end.
still the same error ??

Comment: maybe the problem is because the COUNT( id ) AS pages from behaviour is not passed to the new_table.pages as a number