# Updating db field if data is present

Tags: php, laravel

I cant seem to get my code working 100%.  I am trying to get my code to work in a way like this:

if the column value is empty (`$id = columnName`) then insert into that row.  If there is a "value" found for that `$id` then update the value already saved in the DB.

**Function:**

```
     $socialCheck = SocialSettings::where($id)->first();

       $socialInsert = new SocialSettings;

       $value        = Request::input('value'); 


       if(SocialSettings::where_not_null($id)){

           $socialInsert->$id = $value;
           $socialInsert->save();
   }else{
        $socialCheck->update($value);

   }

    }
```

Comment: If you are using mysql and were willing to prepare a bind statement with [`DB::raw()`](http://fideloper.com/laravel-raw-queries) then you could use a [`REPLACE INTO`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19820724/replace-into-query-syntax) statement

Comment: did u find a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an exemple from a similar question

```
$user = User::firstOrNew(array('name' => Input::get('name')));
$user->foo = Input::get('foo');
$user->save();
```

Like this

```
$socialCheck = SocialSettings::firstOrNew(array('id' => $id));
$socialCheck = Request::input('value');
$socialCheck->save();
```

firstOrNew Laravel [API DOCS](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_firstOrNew)