# MySQL - How to insert or update from source table to target table with different Keys?

Tags: mysql, sql-insert

I have 2 tables with different structures.

```
CREATE TABLE test1
(
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    EmpName VARCHAR(50),
    Empid INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE test2
(
    Empid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    EmpFName VARCHAR(50),   
    EmpLName VARCHAR(50)
);
```

Is there a way to insert rows from test2 table into test1? If the row exists in test1 it should update the row as well. I think it's possible with Merge statement but it's not available for MySQL. Is there a similar function like this in MySQL?

I've looked into *INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE* but the tables should have the same primary keys.

Comment: It has many way to solve this problem. But I think Trigger is your answer.

Comment: Have you looked at [Updatable Views](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/view-updatability.html)?

Comment: check this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15383852/sql-if-exists-update-else-insert-into

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help you.

1. Create `Trigger` to detect when insert/update data in your table `test2`.
2. Inside `Trigger` use `REPLACE INTO` to change data in your table `test1`.

Please check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19820724/replace-into-query-syntax) for additional of `REPLACE INTO` command.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to insert rows from test2 table into test1? If the row exists in test1 it should update the row as well

```sql
UPDATE test1
JOIN test2 USING (Empid)
SET test1.EmpName = CONCAT_WS(' ', EmpFName, EmpLName)
```

Pay attention - `EmpName` max length is 50 whereas total length of combined name may be up to 50+1+50=101, so the combined value may be truncated. Increase max length for `EmpName`.

---

If you need to perform this operation automatically when the data in `test2` is inserted/updated then use AFTER INSERT and AFTER UPDATE triggers, like

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr
AFTER INSERT -- and the same trigger on AFTER UPDATE event
ON test2
FOR EACH ROW
UPDATE test1 
  SET EmpName = CONCAT_WS(' ', NEW.EmpFName, NEW.EmpLName)
  WHERE test1.Empid = NEW.Empid;
```